# How to crop a circular image to inscribed square, then crop to inscribed circle, and finally crop to inscribed square?

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I would like to crop the circular image attached below according to the following:

1. crop input circular image to the unique square inscribed in the circle.
2. crop the square image down to the circle inscribed in the square
3. crop the circular image from the previous step down to square that inscribes image.

I am using python, opencv, and PIL. I have tried cropping with hard coding coordinates, but this obviously causes problems when applied to other images, so I would like a universal solution.

I have included a rough visualization of how I would like to crop it:

In addition, I have included the original image:

A code snippet with brief explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It seems fairly straight-forward to compute the size of the inner square based on the diameter of the circle in the input. You can then directly reach your final goal without the intermediate steps (if that is what you're after).

Comment: @john And you lost attached img

Comment: Does the circle always perfectly fit into the squared picture like in your example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image you want to crop to is, geometrically, **a square centered on the input image, half as large**. This is because you're inscribing twice, each time the square shrinks by the square root of two, and dividing by SQRT(2) twice is the same thing as dividing by 2.

So if you have an input square of side D (or a circular image of diameter D), what you need to do is crop with center (D/2, D/2) and a side of D/2.

Comment: Yes, I just came up with the same solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to perform intermediate crop.

Just calculate result square parameters.

Something like this pseudocode (I'm better in c++):

```
def calcSideOfInscribedSquare(current_size):
    return current_size / sqrt(2)

initial_side = min(image.cols, image.rows)
first_squre_side = calcSideOfInscribedSquare(initial_side)
second_square_side = calcSideOfInscribedSquare(first_squre_side)

cv.Rect result_square(
    image.cols / 2 - second_square_side / 2,
    image.rows / 2 - second_square_side / 2,
    second_square_side,
    second_square_side)

new_image = image(result_square)
```